# How to make Content Search Web part look like OOTB list

Tags: display-template, content-search-web-part

I am trying to query a few lists in subsites and I have been asked to display them or have a look and feel of OOTB Lists. with the capability to filter, sort.

How can I do that? is it easy to build such a thing?

**Edit:**

I found this article : [How to: Create a Simple SharePoint 2013 People Directory](http://www.sharepointconfig.com/2013/05/how-to-create-a-simple-sharepoint-2013-people-directory/) but I don't see it appear in the control dropdown of the web part properties.

And they say XSLT is difficult.

Thank you

Comment: Building one that looks the same is simple, but implementing filtering, paging and sorting that looks and works the same as a list view is a more tedious task

Comment: Let's start first by simply displaying it then I can look how to build filtering and sorting.

Comment: Then you need to make your own display template mimicking the elements and classes that a list view uses.

Comment: I found the blog above but I can't seem to make it work. I don't get it yet how the control dropdown list works and the item one in Content search web part properites.

Comment: Possibly this is a better starting point for learning how to work them: http://blog.comperiosearch.com/blog/2014/06/23/sharepoint-search-display-templates/

Comment: I have created a table display template that supports sorting which have a similar OOTB list look and feel. You can find them in the SPCSR GitHub repository: https://github.com/SPCSR/DisplayTemplates/tree/master/Search%20Display%20Templates/Table%20Layout%20with%20Sorting%20Templates%20(CSWP) https://github.com/SPCSR/DisplayTemplates/tree/master/Search%20Display%20Templates/Table%20Layout%20with%20Multi%20Sort%20Templates%20(CSWP)